# Oracle 11g RSS feed

Tags: oracle, rss

I know Oracle 11g can send out e-mails using utl_smtp, which is pretty neat. I am trying to find some documentation about whether Oracle 11g could also generate an RSS with table updates of some kind. More generally, if I wanted to be notified of table updates, what options do I have besides utl_smtp?

I am looking for a solution that would not require installation of additional programs. In other words, the solution should involve a mail client (preferable) or browser to receive / browse notifications, the Oracle 11g server, and the application proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any built in library for building RSS feeds. There is however the [Alexandria PL/SQL utility library](http://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/) which can - amongst other things - generate RSS feeds. Perhaps it suits your needs, have a look at the `RSS_UTIL_PKG` function as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This would be very useful but we do not administer the database ourselves and we have no guarantee the DBAs will agree to install a third-party package.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your 'no additional programs' rule. You could also use smtp as it is and expose all mails from the db via a custom mail2rss tool that fetches mails from the mailserver and converts them.

Comment: Thanks again. What I gather from our conversation is that smtp is the most straightforward way in our situation. I will accept this answer.